# Spring @Cacheable unless property reference key created by custom key generator

Tags: java, spring, caching

I have the following `getLoggedInCustomer` service, which is slow and is using caching with a custom key generator (which is using multiple fields from a JWT token)

The new requirement (for monitoring) is that we don't want to cache a few customers. For example we don't want to cache the customer where the generated cache key is `123`

The only way I could accomplish this is to include the generated cache key into the result and reference it in the `unless` field of the `@Cacheable` as you can see below:

```
@CacheConfig(keyGenerator = "CustomKeyGenerator")
class CustomerService {


    @Cacheable(value = "customers", unless="#result.key.equals(\"123\")")
    public Customer getLoggedInCustomer() {
        return repository.getLoggedInCustomer; // slow 
    }
}
```

Wondering is it possible to do this without including this generated cache key into the result object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Service
@Log4j2
@CacheConfig(keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
class CustomerService {

    @Cacheable(value = "customers", unless = "@monitoring.monitoringUser()")
    public Customer getLoggedInCustomer() {
        return repository.getLoggedInCustomer; // slow 
    }

}
```

where the `monitoringUser` is from

```
@Component(value = "monitoring")
@Log4j2
class Monitoring {

    @Value("${caching.disable.users:#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}}")
    private List<String> users;

    public boolean monitoringUser() {
        String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        // do not cache
        if (users.contains(name)) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

More details here:

https://zoltanaltfatter.com/2019/07/24/conditional-caching/